# column names of ordered factor in model.matrix in R

Tags: r

I created a design matrix using `model.matrix` function.

If I use ordered factor data, I get `L`, `Q` and `C` suffixes in the column names. ***What do these suffixes mean and how are they mapped to factor levels?*** The help file for `model.matrix` is unclear on this question.

```
head( model.matrix( as.formula( ~ ps ), 
                    model.frame( as.formula( ~ ps ),
                                 data.frame(ps = factor( x =  sample(x = c( 'none', '3XLT', '41X',  '3X' ),
                                                                     size = 50,
                                                                     replace = TRUE ),
                                                         levels = c( '3X', '3XLT', '41X', 'none' ),
                                                         ordered = TRUE ) ) ) ) )

#   (Intercept)       ps.L ps.Q       ps.C
# 1           1 -0.2236068 -0.5  0.6708204
# 2           1  0.6708204  0.5  0.2236068
# 3           1  0.6708204  0.5  0.2236068
# 4           1  0.2236068 -0.5 -0.6708204
# 5           1  0.6708204  0.5  0.2236068
# 6           1 -0.2236068 -0.5  0.6708204
```

If I use unordered factor, I can easily trace the mapping of the column by its column names.

```
head( model.matrix( as.formula( ~ ps ), 
                    model.frame( as.formula( ~ ps ),
                                 data.frame(ps = factor( x =  sample(x = c( 'none', '3XLT', '41X',  '3X' ),
                                                                     size = 50,
                                                                     replace = TRUE ),
                                                         levels = c( '3X', '3XLT', '41X', 'none' ) ) ) ) ) )

#   (Intercept) ps3XLT ps41X psnone
# 1           1      0     0      1
# 2           1      1     0      0
# 3           1      0     0      1
# 4           1      1     0      0
# 5           1      0     0      0
# 6           1      1     0      0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still do not know the meaning of those suffixes, probably some historical reasons attached to it.

After debugging `model.matrix` function, there was a call to the `C_modelmatrix` inside it.

```
.External2(C_modelmatrix, t, data)
```

For ordered factor `contrasts.poly` is used to get the design matrix using `make.poly` function defined inside this call. After getting the design matrix, the column names are modified and they are given those strange suffixes for the columns 2 - 4. The first column is ignored and if there are more than 4 columns, they will be left with the name as defined by the `make.poly` function.

```
contr <- make.poly(n, scores)
if (contrasts) {
  dn <- colnames(contr)
  dn[2:min(4, n)] <- c(".L", ".Q", ".C")[1:min(3, n - 1)]
  colnames(contr) <- dn
  contr[, -1, drop = FALSE]
}
```

In summary, those suffixes mean nothing, but they are mapped to the levels of the ordered factor from 2 to 4. For factor levels having length greater than 4, no renaming is applied. See an example below.

```
head( model.matrix( as.formula( ~ ps ), 
                    model.frame( as.formula( ~ ps ),
                                 data.frame(ps = factor( x =  sample(x = c( 'none', '3XLT', '2X', '41X',  '3X' ),
                                                                     size = 50,
                                                                     replace = TRUE ),
                                                         levels = c( '3X', '3XLT', '2X', '41X', 'none' ),
                                                         ordered = TRUE ) ) ) ) )

#   (Intercept)       ps.L       ps.Q          ps.C       ps^4
# 1           1  0.0000000 -0.5345225 -4.095972e-16  0.7171372
# 2           1  0.0000000 -0.5345225 -4.095972e-16  0.7171372
# 3           1  0.3162278 -0.2672612 -6.324555e-01 -0.4780914
# 4           1 -0.6324555  0.5345225 -3.162278e-01  0.1195229
# 5           1  0.3162278 -0.2672612 -6.324555e-01 -0.4780914
# 6           1 -0.6324555  0.5345225 -3.162278e-01  0.1195229
```

The output of `contr`

```
contr <- make.poly(n, scores)
Browse[6]> contr
#             ^0         ^1         ^2            ^3         ^4
# [1,] 0.4472136 -0.6324555  0.5345225 -3.162278e-01  0.1195229
# [2,] 0.4472136 -0.3162278 -0.2672612  6.324555e-01 -0.4780914
# [3,] 0.4472136  0.0000000 -0.5345225 -4.095972e-16  0.7171372
# [4,] 0.4472136  0.3162278 -0.2672612 -6.324555e-01 -0.4780914
# [5,] 0.4472136  0.6324555  0.5345225  3.162278e-01  0.1195229
```

**EDIT:**
The expansion for L, Q, C in the contrast matrix of ordered factor corresponds to Linear, Quadratic and Cubic terms. The naming of further degrees of polynomial terms (greater than 3) are indicated by the numeric value of degree of that polynomial term.