# How to get 0-1 dummies for ordered categorical variables in lm in R?

Tags: r, lm, categorical-data

When running linear models with a categorical dependent variable in `R`, this variable is internally recoded into dummy variables:

```
unord <- data.frame(y = c(1, 2, 3, 12, 11, 13, 101, 103, 102, 1003, 1002, 1001),
             cat = factor(rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 3), ordered = FALSE))
model.matrix(lm(y~cat, data = unord))

   (Intercept) catB catC catD
1            1    0    0    0
2            1    0    0    0
3            1    0    0    0
4            1    1    0    0
5            1    1    0    0
6            1    1    0    0
7            1    0    1    0
8            1    0    1    0
9            1    0    1    0
10           1    0    0    1
11           1    0    0    1
12           1    0    0    1
```

what I like.
If the categorical dependent variable however is ordered, the dummy variables are for some reason less intuitive:

```
ord <- data.frame(y = c(1, 2, 3, 12, 11, 13, 101, 103, 102, 1003, 1002, 1001),
                cat = factor(rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 3), ordered = TRUE))
model.matrix(lm(y~cat, data = ord))

   (Intercept)      cat.L cat.Q      cat.C
1            1 -0.6708204   0.5 -0.2236068
2            1 -0.6708204   0.5 -0.2236068
3            1 -0.6708204   0.5 -0.2236068
4            1 -0.2236068  -0.5  0.6708204
5            1 -0.2236068  -0.5  0.6708204
6            1 -0.2236068  -0.5  0.6708204
7            1  0.2236068  -0.5 -0.6708204
8            1  0.2236068  -0.5 -0.6708204
9            1  0.2236068  -0.5 -0.6708204
10           1  0.6708204   0.5  0.2236068
11           1  0.6708204   0.5  0.2236068
12           1  0.6708204   0.5  0.2236068
```

The question is **How can I get "usual" dummies for ordered categorical variables?** Note: the question is not about how to use the information from the ordering correctly (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33413/continuous-dependent-variable-with-ordinal-independent-variable).

Comment: when you saved the results in a data.frame, e.g. `a`, then you could do `factor(a$cat.L, levels = unique(a$cat.L), labels = 1:length(unique(a$cat.L)))`

Comment: @Jimbou, `a$cat.L` is `NULL`...

Comment: @Jimbou `broom::tidy(model.matrix(lm(y~cat, data = ord)))` gives the same dummies as `model.matrix(lm(y~cat, data = ord))`.

Comment: Sorry try this `a <- broom::tidy(model.matrix(lm(y~cat, data = ord)))` Then the factor thing.

Comment: If I get it right, you are basically saying that I should  make my ordered variable unordered, right? This wouldn't help me. But if you mean something else, can you provide it in a clear answer?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what the question really is. (forgive my ignorance). Internally, R makes ordered factors into contrasts using the `contrasts.poly()` function. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42501864/column-names-of-ordered-factor-in-model-matrix-in-r). So you are going to have to make a choice of how to represent the information. The above suggestions ignore ordering. Or, you can use the default `poly()` and live with that consequence. [Link to a better depiction of contrasts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105115/polynomial-contrasts-for-regression)

Comment: @jacobsg, your comment seems to go into the right direction. How can I say `lm()` it should not use the linear, quadratic, cubic contrasts (without changing my data)?

Comment: I see two options: create the dummy variables yourself, or remove the ordering from the factor. For the first, a function like: `psych::dummy.code()` works. The second is running factor again with order equaling false.

Comment: is this the sort of thing you want, either  `model.matrix(lm(y ~ factor(cat, ordered=FALSE), data = ord))` or `model.matrix(lm(y~cat, data = ord, contrasts = list(cat=contr.treatment)))`

Comment: @user20650 `model.matrix(lm(y~cat, data = ord, contrasts = list(cat=contr.treatment)))`is the solution. Do you want to post it as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: All factors have an order for their levels. The only reasons to use an *ordered* factor is if you want to use the polynomial contrasts by default or if you want to be able to test comparisons with `<` or `>`. You saw that the default `ordered = FALSE` works for you dummy variables. There's an easy fix below for the `ordered = TRUE` case, but I would ask if you really need `ordered = TRUE` at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force which contrast is used by using the `contrasts` argument, in `lm` or as below in `model.matrix` (as I removed extra `lm` call)

```
model.matrix(y ~ cat, data = ord, contrasts = list(cat=contr.treatment))
```

If you have more than one factor column you can do

```
nms <- names(ord)[sapply(ord, is.factor)] # get names of factor variables
model.matrix(y ~ cat, data = ord, 
                contrasts = sapply(nms, function(x) list(contr.treatment)))
```